# When i tried to access my Macintosh HD i got the following error :

Tags: boot, mount, hard-drive

```
Error mounting /dev/sda2 at /media/mint/Macintosh HD1: Command-line `mount -t "hfsplus" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid" "/dev/sda2" "/media/mint/Macintosh HD1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

Please can anyone help i need to recover my data ?

Comment: Could you give us some more details?  Please could you edit your question to include the output of `dmesg` (which will be long), and also `uname -a`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding

**Solution that worked for me:**

So first of all, to be able to read mac drives in Ubuntu you need hfsprogs.

**sudo apt-get install hfsprogs**

Then i fixed my drive by this:

Run the following command (replacing XY with the correct device) to fix the drive:

**sudo fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/sdXY**

P.S Thank God now i'm recovering my data.